# Objective c: Delegate method calls implicitly to an other instance

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a class which takes a *delegate* and of course calls the delegate methods at some point in time, in this example the `NSURLConnection`:

```
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]
                                   initWithRequest:request
                                   delegate:delegate];
```

I want to *intercept* the `didFailWithError` method of the *delegate*, i.e. the NSURLConnection instance does not call the method of the delegate directly instead it calls a different method, which calls the `didFailWithError` eventually.

What I would like to do is something like "inheritance" on object instead of a class level. For example in javascript I would do something like:

```
// Set the original delegate as prototype
var myDecoratedDelegate = Object.create(delegate);
// save the original method
var didFailWithError = delegate.didFailWithError;
// Decorate the didFailWithError method
myDecoratedDelegate.didFailWithError = function() {
    // do something
    didFailWithError()
}
var connection = new Connection(request, myDecoratedDelegate);
```

In this way I would archive that every method of the original delegate gets called normally, except the function I would like to decorate.

I know, objective c is not javascript, but I am pretty new to objective c and there is maybe a elegant solution.

However, I am aware that with `method_setImplementation` you can change the implementation of an instances methods. However, I think it would be rather surprising for the callee if I change the original behavior of a class and would prefer not to do so.

An acceptable solution for me would also be to inherit the `NSURLConnection` class and change the way how it calls its delegate. However, I don't know how to do so, since this is not part of the public API of the NSURLConnection class.

Comment: "However, I think it would be rather surprising for the callee if I change the original behavior of a class and would prefer not to do so." - isn't that exactly what you're doing with the Javascript?

Comment: No. I use the original delegate as the prototype for the decorated delegate, i.e. every method call on the decorated delegate will call the original delegate, as long it is not overwritten in the decorated delegate.